# How to cross reference nested enumeration lists?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, nesting

Within theorems, I have nested enumeration lists:

> 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc.
>
> 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, etc.

For referencing to

> 1.1 to 1.3 and 2.4

I tried to use the usual command `\cref{en1-1,en1-2,en1-3,en2-4}`. However, it does not work correctly since it ignores the first level of numbering and thus yields the wrong result

> 1.1 to 2.4

Is there way to fix that so that higher levels of numbering are considered as well?
I am looking for an automated solution and not the manual workaround `\cref{en1-1,en1-2,en1-3} and \cref{en2-4}`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\parindent0pt

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*, labelsep=10pt, itemsep=1pt, label=\theTheorem.\arabic*, align=parleft}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
This is the first Theorem.
\end{Theorem} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{en:1-1} This is item 1.1
\item \label{en:1-2} This is item 1.2
\item \label{en:1-3} This is item 1.3
\item \label{en:1-4} This is item 1.4
\end{enumerate}

\begin{Theorem}
This is the second Theorem.
\end{Theorem} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{en:2-1} This is item 2.1
\item \label{en:2-2} This is item 2.2
\item \label{en:2-3} This is item 2.3
\item \label{en:2-4} This is item 2.4
\end{enumerate}

The references to \cref{en:1-1,en:1-2,en:1-3,en:2-4} go wrong.

The references to \cref{en:1-2,en:1-3,en:1-4,,en:2-1} are even more strange.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo If I use `\label[thoerem]{...}` in my MWE then only "items" is replaced by "theorems", but it still references to "1.1 to 2.4" instead of "1.1 to 1.3 and 2.4"

Comment: @JohnKormylo It only considers the lowest level of numbering, so it assumes en:1-1 and en:2-1 to be the same and thus ignores it the second time. 
Thus, I am looking for a solution that indeed considers the higher levels as well.

Comment: From page 8 of the manual, you need a double comma to get `and` instead of `to`.

Comment: @John Kormylo: In this specific case, it would work, but it is a manually "forced" solution that does not work in general, because if you, for example, reference to `\cref{en:1-2,en:1-3,en:1-4,,en:2-1}`, the result is still wrong and rather strange (see edited MWE).